# Record in the model field

Tags: django

I make an auction site.
There is a model Lot

```
class Lot(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lot'

    lot_created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    lot_author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', default='1')
    lot_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    lot_description = models.TextField(default='',)
    lot_start_price = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=100)
    lot_last_bet = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.lot_name
```

When printed in a template, each lot has a button "bid". 
How to record in the field "lot_last_bet"(Login of the user who made the bet) when you click the "bid"?

Comment: try storing 'lot_last_bet= request.user' in save method

Comment: I would recommend to make lot_last_bet also a ForeignKey to user like lot_author, since you want to store a reference to a user.